# DotCMIS RepositoryInfo.LatestChangeLogToken returns null just after enabling ChangeLog on Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis, dotcmis

This code returns `null`:

```
session.Binding.GetRepositoryService()
    .GetRepositoryInfo(session.RepositoryInfo.Id, null).LatestChangeLogToken
```

on an Alfresco Community 4.2.e server, just after I [turned on ChangeLog](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/CmisSync/wiki/How-to-enable-CMIS%27-ChangeLog-feature-on-Alfresco) and restarted. Before enabling ChangeLog, I had been using this server and adding files, if that matters.

Is this normal? Is it because I have not touched any file since enabling ChangeLog?
Are there any other situations where a `null` output is normal?

After I add a document, the result is not `null` anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Alfresco.

The workaround is to perform a change (for instance create and remove a folder) before using the repository.

The bug has been fixed in Alfresco 5.0.2.

Details: https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/MNT-13529